# getting count of multiple columns and show in next column

Tags: drupal, drupal-10

I have a content type where the data is as follows:

```
Desc        Distribution-1      Distribution-2      Distribution-3
south           14                  5                   8
north-k         2                   10                  1
outer-k         5                   4                   7
```

Now what I have to show is the total count of the three columns and display the result and also the individual count of each column. How can I do that?

```
Desc        Distribution-1      Distribution-2      Distribution-3      Total
south           14                  5                   8               27
north-k         2                   10                  1               13
outer-k         5                   4                   7               16
Desc-total      21                  19                  16
```

I do not want to create extra field for `Total` and `Desc-total` because it will show only in report, no need to store in database.

Answer (score 1):

you can archive this in many ways,
We need the data to calculate just before the page render

1. you can do this by assigning a template file for your content type and do the calculation in your template file where all your required values are available
2. Do the calculation in your themeName.them file and set the value in a variable this variable should be available in your node template file and just print that variable as you need

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {  
  if ($variables['node']->bundle() === 'content_machine_name'){  
    $d1 = $variables['node']->get('Distribution_1')->getValue();  
    $d2 = $variables['node']->get('Distribution_2')->getValue();  
    $d3 = $variables['node']->get('Distribution_3')->getValue();  
    $DistributionTotal = $d1 + $d2 + $d3;  
    $variables['DistributionTotal'] = $DistributionTotal;  
  }  
}
```

Now you can simply print this variable having the total of all Distributions
print this variable in your node type .twig file like this {{ DistributionTotal }}
Hope this makes sense